# Utilize model methods and properties in another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Thank you in advance for your help.

I am using inheritance to leverage properties from a base mode like this: `HomeModel : BaseModel`.

This is working as expected, but now I want to take it one step further. I want to use it one additional level down so the new model inherits everything from `HomeModel`.

I created a `NavModel` like this

```
public class NavModel : HomeModel {
    public string CloudVersion{get;set;}
    public IMxUser Usr {get;set;}
    public ILocalizer Localizer {get;set;}
    public NavModel(IMxUser mxUser, ILocalizer localizer)
    {
        Localizer = localizer;
        Usr = mxUser;
        CloudVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cloudVersion"];
    }
}
```

but  it threw the error

```
'HomeModel' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.
```

Is it a bad idea for me to daisy-chain like this? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?

**UPDATE**

Prior to adding the empty constructor, this is the standard HomeModel constructor:

```
public HomeModel(IMxUser mxUser, ILocalizer localizer)
{
    Localizer = localizer;
    Usr = mxUser;
    BomSearchJavascriptMethod = GetSearchJavascriptMethod(MnxConst.SearchOptions.BILL_OF_MATERIAL, EnterBOMSearchKeyStr);
    POSearchJavascriptMethod = GetSearchJavascriptMethod(MnxConst.SearchOptions.PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER, EnterBOMSearchKeyStr);
}
```

It would be nice if I could leverage the standard `HomeModel` in related models, but I am not sure how to pass those with my current method of reference.

Comment: Since there is no default constructor on you HomeModel, there seem to be required dependencies that you will have to satisfy. Just adding a default constructor might leave this dependency unresolved, what causes problems (probably ````NullReferenceException````) downstream.

Comment: You are talking about inheritance. I notice you are initializing the NavModel with static properties from the Model class. This is somthing that you should not do. Maybe the error is there?

Comment: Assuming you know how to instantiate a ````HomeModel```` you can provide a similar constructor to the derived models, passing the parameters to the constructor of the base class ````HomeModel```` using the ````base```` syntax.

Comment: @paulroho I can do something like `var hm = new HomeModel(mxUser, localizer);`, but I don't want to create local variables in `NavModel` and pass the `HomeModel` variables to it. Are you referring to something else? I would like to be able to just use the `Home` and `Base` model properties like the are already part of `NaveModel`

Comment: @davids I think there is a misunderstanding: I mean directly passing the parameters of the ````NavModel```` constructor to the ````HomeModel```` constructor using the base class initializer: ````public HomeModel(IMxUser mxUser, ILocalizer localizer) :base(mxUser, localizer) {...}````

Comment: @davids The code you are showing us contains no ````if````. Please post the whole razor view.

Comment: @paulroho I found the issue. The ifs were just fine. I was missing a </li> which caused the if to fail. Your solution of `:base()` fixed my original problem. If you will post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize the base class as well using the initializer like this:

```
public HomeModel(IMxUser mxUser, ILocalizer localizer)
  : base(mxUser, localizer)
{
    // ...
}
```